# How to get correct double type from C++ using ctypes when restype = c_double?

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I'm creating a trigonometry calculator to test output of an IoT product. The testware is built with python while the product's firmware is built with C++. I would like to test some math functions such SIN. However, the `numpy.sin()` output and C++ math.sin output would differ on big number/complex floating point number. For example, I have to calculate this number: `numpy.float64(1.7976931348623157e+308)`. I decided to use C++ cmath library to get the result of sin( `np.float64(1.7976931348623157e+308)` ) and to use ctypes to interface between C++ code and python.

However the return type from ctypes is not as expected. I expect it to be double (equivalence to `numpy.float64`). I have set the `restype = c_double`.

What I have now:
a. a DLL project in VS2017
b. python code to call

Here they are the codes to calculate from C++ DLL project and respective python code to invoke:

CalculatorTrigonometry.h

```
#pragma once
#ifdef CALCULATORTRIGONOMETRY_EXPORTS
#define CALCULATORTRIGONOMETRY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CALCULATORTRIGONOMETRY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" 
{
    CALCULATORTRIGONOMETRY_API float calc_sin_float(const float val);

    CALCULATORTRIGONOMETRY_API double calc_sin_double(const double val);
}
```

CalculatorTrigonometry.cpp

```
// CalculatorTrigonometry.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CalculatorTrigonometry.h"
#include <cmath>


 float calc_sin_float(const float val)
 {
    float res = sin(val);
    return res;
 }

double calc_sin_double(const double val)
{
    double res = sin(val);
    return res;
}
```

The codes above compiled to a dll using release and x86 build configuration.

I invoke this dll using numpy as below:
try_dll.py

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct

hllDll = npct.load_library ("CalculatorTrigonometry", '.')
hllDll.calc_sin_double.argtype = [c_double]
hllDll.calc_sin_double.restype = c_double

b = np.float64(1.7976931348623157e+308)

ctypes_b = npct.as_ctypes(b)
print type(ctypes_b)

print type(hllDll.calc_sin_double(ctypes_b))
```

As you can see above, my intention is to get double type output for further processing in our testware but I kept getting float instead. Anyone does have idea about what happened? I might miss something.

Comment: A C `double` is considered to be a python float type as given by [this table](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) (look at the python types).  If your concern is that your last print always print `float` then it's perfectly normal and expected.

Comment: `numpy.sin` and Python's `math.sin` will all give the same answer.  Python `float`, numpy `float64` and C/C++ `double` are all equivalent IEEE 754 double precision floating point numbers.  What is the real issue?  You don't need `ctypes` for this.

Comment: I need to provide workaround because sin from python (windows based) output and math.sin compiled with VS Studio output are different for complex floating point number from the ones compiled with mingw or unix/posix based compiler and also the device under test.

I can't switch to linux because of my employer policy. What I can do is installing mingw compiler and create a separate library so my python can make use of that library.

Comment: @Oscar Then your question should illustrate a complex number example, not double.  As Neitsa said, C double and Python float are the same thing so your question as is doesn't make sense.